# Easiest way in Bourne shell to extract strings from a line of text?

Tags: sh

Let's say I'm doing a `grep` and it returns this line:

```
Invalid value (48) on line 3
```

How can I easily pull that value `48` into a variable in Bourne shell?

Comment: With pure "classic" Bourne Shell commands, or can you use external tools? No Bash or anything recent?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the pattern is always to get the value in the first pair of parenthesis, then cut is your best friend.

```
myvar=$(echo 'Invalid value (48) on line 3' | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1)
```

this extracts the value between the parens.

Comment: `$()` is not part of SVID and thus not strictly "Bourne Shell" only. It's defined in POSIX though.

Comment: yes, if it is indeed the original sh, though in most linux distributions /bin/sh is just a symlink to /bin/bash. however, backstick should work, if $() does not. just remove $ and replace () with ``.

Comment: Yup, just wanted to mention it for completeness since the OP seemed to be very specific about `sh` and not Bash and companions.

Answer (score 0):

`echo 'Invalid value (48) on line 3'| awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'`